# e.graphics.hasmorepages = true doesn't print on the next page VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am having hard time printing multiple pages on print document. It keeps printing everything on the first page even though I have new page set up in my code. Please help. Here is my code:`

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim yTop As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Dim leftmargin = e.MarginBounds.Left
        Dim MyPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
        Dim regFont = New Font("Arial", 10)
        Dim smallFont = New Font("Arial", 8)
        Dim xsFont = New Font("Arial", 6)
        Dim micrFont = New Font("MICR", 10)
        Dim myprintfont = New Font("Arial", 12)
        Dim Bigfont = New Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim BldFnt = New Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim fCtr As New StringFormat
        fCtr.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        Dim frt As New StringFormat
        frt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
        Dim flft As New StringFormat
        flft.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
        'Dim mrc As String = ""
        Dim lpos As Integer = My.Settings.ChkLeft
        Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim mrc As String = ""
        Dim p As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim ct As Integer = dgChecks.SelectedRows.Count
        Static totaChecksPrinted As Integer
        If totaChecksPrinted < dgChecks.SelectedRows.Count - 1 Then
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgChecks.SelectedRows
                st = row.Cells("CheckNumber").Value
                Dim strSQL1 As String
                strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM QryCheckPrint WHERE CheckNumber In( " & st & ")"
                If HQCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then HQCon.Open()
                Dim ccmda As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL1, HQCon)
                Dim drc2 As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
                Dim HasRows As Boolean = False
                drc2 = ccmda.ExecuteReader
                If drc2.HasRows Then
                    While drc2.Read

                        y += My.Settings.ChkTop
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("CorpName"), Bigfont, Brushes.Black, lpos, y, frt)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("CheckNumber"), Bigfont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 640, y + 1, frt)
                        y += 40

                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("Date"), smallFont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 640, y + 6, frt)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("Date", myprintfont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 580, y + 5, frt)
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, lpos + 620, y + 25, lpos + 730, y + 25)

                        y += 60

                        e.Graphics.DrawString("Pay to the", smallFont, Brushes.Black, lpos, y, frt)
                        y += 15
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("order of", smallFont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 10, y, frt)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("Name"), myprintfont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 90, y - 10, frt)
                        If Not IsDBNull(drc2.Item("Amount")) Then
                            e.Graphics.DrawString("$" & Format(drc2.Item("Amount"), "n2"), myprintfont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 640, y - 5, frt)
                        End If
                        y += 15
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, lpos + 50, y, lpos + 640, y)
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, lpos + 50, y + 30, lpos + 640, y + 30)
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, lpos + 640, y - 25, lpos + 640, y)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("**" & Functions.AmountInWords(drc2.Item("Amount")) & "**", regFont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 100, y + 10, frt)

                        y += 40
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("BankName"), smallFont, Brushes.Black, lpos, y, frt)
                        y += 15
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("BankAddress"), smallFont, Brushes.Black, lpos, y, frt)
                        y += 15
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("City") & " " & drc2.Item("State") & ", " & drc2.Item("Zip"), smallFont, Brushes.Black, lpos, y, frt)
                        mrc = "o" & drc2.Item("CheckNumber") & "o T" & drc2.Item("ABA") & "T" & drc2.Item("AccountNumber") & "o"
                        y += 30
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("Description"), smallFont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 80, y, frt)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("For", regFont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 30, y, frt)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("By", regFont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 480, y, frt)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(drc2.Item("StoreCode"), xsFont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 400, y, frt)
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, lpos + 30, y + 20, lpos + 440, y + 20)
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, lpos + 500, y + 20, lpos + 720, y + 20)

                        y = y + My.Settings.MicrPos
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(mrc, micrFont, Brushes.Black, lpos + 100, y, frt)
                        y = y + My.Settings.ChkBottom

                        j += 1
                        totaChecksPrinted += 1
                    End While
                End If
                drc2.Close()
                ccmda = Nothing
                If (y > e.MarginBounds.Bottom) Then       'Print new page
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    y = 0
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If HQCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then HQCon.Close()
    End Sub`
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time the `PrintPage` event is raised, you should print only the data that goes on that page.  If you have more data to print, set `HasMorePages` to True and then `Exit Sub`.  Then the `PrintPage` method will be called again for the next page.  You will need to keep track of what you have already printed between pages somehow.  Something like this:

```
'Class level variable perhaps
Dim pageNumberToPrint As Integer = 1

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    'Print the data that goes on the current page (pageNumberToPrint)
    If pageNumberToPrint = 1 Then
        'Print page number 1
    Else
        If pageNumberToPrint = 2 Then
            'Print page number 2
        Else
            'Print page number 3
        End If
    End If

    'If you're at the end of the page, and still have more data to print
    If (y > e.MarginBounds.Bottom) Then       'Print new page
        e.HasMorePages = True
        y = 0
        pageNumberToPrint += 1
        Exit Sub        'The PrintPage event handler will be raised again
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually that's is my real problem. It either prints all pages to the first page or prints multiple pages but prints the first page to all pages.
I am kind of lost in between:)

Comment: @Aras - Your `PrintPage` handler needs to be able to know which page it is currently printing and only print the data for that page (see updated code).  You need to keep track of what has already been printed so that you don't print the same data more than one time.  In your original code you were setting the `HasMorePages` property, but you did not exit the sub.  In your code, you will probably have to do the query outside the sub.